# How to override layout xml file of another file module in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, layout, magento-1.7

I have a module `Askit` which on following directory

```
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tm/askit/
```

form.phtml page contains in below directory

```
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/tm/askit/question/form.phtml
```

I want to update its layout xml to set meta data of its phtml pages.

As I am referring [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/cant-find-where-to-change-meta-description-keywords-and-title)

http://example.com/questions/

I want to set meta for above page from my theme local.xml file

here is layout xml directory url -

```
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/argento/mall/layout
```

I have write below code in my theme layout local.xml file but its not updating meta for this page -

```
<askit_question_index>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="setTitle"><value>Ask an Expert and Get Answers - </value></action>
      <action method="setDescription"><value>Ask a question and get an answer to your question from a Expert related to your purchased product </value></action>
   </reference>
</askit_question_index>
```

Comment: Make sure your local.xml parsed successfully. Check var/log .

Comment: local.xml working fine. I have updated Meta's for other pages using same xml. Only problem having that page.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it should be work from the local.xml as per above mention code. But if not than you can add the meta information through controller.

Add below code into `indexAction` of your controller (`QuestionController`) after calling `$this->loadLayout(); and $this->loadLayout();`

```
$headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
if ($headBlock){
    $headBlock->setTitle($this->__('Ask an Expert and Get Answers'));
    $headBlock->setDescription($this->__('Ask a question and get an answer to your question from a Expert related to your purchased product'));
    $headBlock->setKeywords($this->__('Meta keywords here'));
}
```